# Optimize MySql Select query in PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, database, optimization, foreach

Please help me optimize the following foreach loop. It works perfectly with small arrays, when the loop is short but the problem is that sometimes, when the array is way to big, it forces the query to loop inside the foreach to many times, and that is causing my server to jam throwing a 503 error. I need to somehow do the query outside the foreach but still be able to select WHERE cat=$id[0] AND sub = $id[1] AND fir = $id[2].

```
foreach($array as $id){
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE cat=$id[0] AND sub = $id[1] AND fir = $id[2]");

    $thiss = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    echo $thiss['name']; 
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing a foreach loop of queries instead of one well written query in the first place?

Comment: How should i do that? Keep in mind that i need to select where cat = x and sub = x and fir = x every time...

Comment: Can you please var_dump the $array so that I can get an idea of what the array contains/what you're truly trying to do in the grand scheme?

Comment: array(30) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "10" [1]=> string(1) "3" [2]=> string(2) "12" } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "10" [1]=> string(1) "3" [2]=> string(2) "13" } ..

Comment: I have an array that looks like this : [0] => 1,2,3 [1] => 2,4,12 [2] => 1,3,7 and so on.. those "random numbers" are colected in a previous form.. and they all link to an complex database with category subcategory and firm id.. where for example [0] => 1(category), 2(subcategory), 3(firm).. so this is why i need to select all the firms with the foreach.. it works, but it takes alot of time when the array is bigger then 20 or 50 key..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going into the details of why I suggest you should reconsider your query logic, but for the task at hand try this:

```
$where=array();
foreach($array as $id){
  $where[]="cat=$id[0] AND sub = $id[1] AND fir = $id[2]";
}
$sql='SELECT * FROM table WHERE ('.implode(') OR (',$where).')';
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while ($thiss = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  echo $thiss['name'];
```

Comment: Thanks alot pall. Exacly what i needed! Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ands = array();
foreach ($array as $id) {
    $ands[] = "(cat=$id[0] AND sub = $id[1] AND fir = $id[2])";
}
$ors = implode(' OR ', $ands);
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name FROM TABLE WHERE $ors";
while ($thiss = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $thiss['name'];
}
```

Comment: $ors = implode(' OR ', $ors); NEEDS TO BE $ors = implode(' OR ', $ands); AND mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch.. Thansk alot this method really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$cat = $sub = $fir = '';
foreach($array as $id){
  $cat .= $id[0].',';
  $sub .= $id[1].',';
  $fir .= $id[2].',';
}
$cat = substr_replace($cat, '', -1);
$sub = substr_replace($sub, '', -1);
$fir = substr_replace($fir, '', -1);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE `cat` IN ($cat) AND `sub` IN($sub) AND `fir` IN ($fir)";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
   echo $row['name']; 
}
```